# how to make css-purge to handle my css files in order I wrote

Tags: css, duplicates, redundancy, css-purge

I want my exported file to have css lines to be in the order I wanted but it is not. 
How can I set css-purge to purge my css files in the order It should be and the order I put it in.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to share an example for me to fully understand your issue but in general, depending on the rules optimised, your CSS will change, especially if there was a duplicate rule or declaration removed.

My guess is that you want to keep the CSS in a readable format and not fully optimised, to do that, you can use the following config settings to keep the CSS in a "prettified" format:

```
"trim": false,
"trim_keep_non_standard_inline_comments": false,
"trim_removed_rules_previous_comment": true,
"trim_comments": false,
"trim_whitespace": false,
"trim_breaklines": false,
"trim_last_semicolon": false,
```